# Use both a variable and newline in BSD sed?

Tags: sed, osx, bsd

I can do this for example

```
sed 's/\>\</\>\
</g'
```

To replace `><` with

```
>
<
```

However, say I want a variable, like this:

```
 sed 's/\>\</\>\
<$1/g'
```

It will interpret it as literally `$1`. To fix this, I use `"` instead of `'`.

Like this:

```
sed "s/\>\</\>\
<$1/g"
```

But it doesn't understand the newline when I use `"`. `\n` does not work either.

Comment: "it doesn't understand the newline".. does it understand `\n`?

Comment: @muru No, I already said that. It interprets it as a literal `\n`. Same thing with `-e` if that would change anything.

Comment: Yep, didn't notice that. Which shell are you using? `sed` will only get the pattern after the shell does quote removal, etc., so if quoting causes a problem, the shell is probably the culprit.

Comment: @muru I am using bash.

Comment: What if you do `'s/></>\[enter]<'"$SHELL/g"`?

Comment: `bad flag in substitute command: 'b'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32886/discussion-between-muru-and-displayname).

Comment: Argh, dammit, that was intended to be `$1`, not `$SHELL`. I don't know why I wrote `$SHELL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what quoting mystery is behind this, but if single quotes help with the newline, you can mix and match with double quotes for the variable:

```
sed 's/></>\
<'"$1/g"
```

Comment: double-quotes eat backslash escaped newlines. `"This" == "T\\nhis"`